# How to create logger file i.e. text file in OS file system for the Outlook addin development(HTML+JQuery/Javascript) for MAC/Windows OS?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

How to create logger file i.e. text file in OS file system for the Outlook addin development(HTML+JQuery/Javascript) for MAC/Windows OS?
Text File should be created at OS file system at AppData folder under logged in User.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what you have developed and what problem you are facing?

Comment: Vorlon is one solution but it works only for Outlook MAC.I need to debug the web addin in windows too.

Answer (score 0):

You could find [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-and-debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio) on how to debug your add-in, and console.log usually helps a lot for debugging.